# Disable prompts in Microsoft Excel when saving a CSV file

Tags: microsoft-excel, csv, spreadsheet

I have to download multiple csv reports from the Internet throughout the day, make a tiny change to them, and save the change.  Excel adds 3 completely unnecessary dialogs to what should really be a 5-second operation.

1. It makes you select a file name in a "Save As..." dialog, even though you just want to save  the existing file
2. It makes you confirm the file name, because it thinks you're overwriting the original file
3. It asks you if you really want to save in the CSV format

Is there a way to kill at least one or two of these dialogs, but ideally all of them?  This is completely infuriating.

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This deals with 3 prompts, not just 1.  Also, that  solution is for 1 file only.  The macro has to be run on each new file.  My issue is dealing with a large number of files.

Comment: You could use another software such as Notepas++ for this purpose. It lets you handle multiple files in tabs and is much simpler for .csv files. Unless of-course you need any of MS Excel features.

Comment: I'm open to using other programs, but I need the data displayed as a table instead of a bunch of data, and I need to be able to sort the columns from smallest to largest.  Those are the only functions I need.

Comment: [try this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11220537/vba-workbooks-close-without-being-prompted-to-if-the-user-wants-to-save)

Comment: @Raystafarian What's the code they are referring to?  I am not familiar with customizing Excel.  Where does this code go?

Comment: `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` always does the trick for me in macros. (Remember to set back to true at the end!). EDIT: as referenced in Raystafarian's link.

Comment: @AndiMohr Please see my comment above

Comment: @KnocksX press F11 to enter the VBA editor. Double-click `Modules` in the folder menu on the left. You should see the VBA code that tells your macro what to do. Add `Application.DisplayAlerts = False` right at the start of the macro (after the `Sub YourMacroName()` bit). Then before `End Sub` at the end, add `Application.DisplayAlerts = True` to switch alerts back on again. HTH

Answer (score 9):

I have consulted multiple sources, and there is no fix for Microsoft Office.

However, I installed LibreOffice, and it handles CSV files the exactly correct way.  I made LibreOffice the default program for opening CSV files, and the problem is now solved.